# VM web console using Firefox causes duplicate characters, Chrome and IE do not have issue

Tags: firefox, doubletake

We are using VCSA 6.7 with five esxi 6.7 hosts & multiple vms are are running inside the esxi hosts.
We are facing "Double Typing" issue when we open vm & start typing using Mozila firefox (Latest version) & The same issue do not shoe when we access v through chrome or IE.
Looking for the earliest Response from your side

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do the needfull

Comment: Hi guys
Looking for your kind response

Comment: Looking for the solution

Comment: Looking for the solution, please let me know if you have to fix it.

Comment: Hi, Looking for your kind response regarding the double typing issue in vmware machine. Hoping for positive response